# catch the input event when a value is entered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input field, let's say for an email

I need to get two events from this field in javascript

The first is click events when I click on that field. The second is when I have already entered a value and released this field by going to another element on the page

With the click event, everything is clear, but how can I get the second event after the input?

```js
$('#inputEmail').on('click', function () {
    console.log('click');
});
```

```css
#inputEmail {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form action="#">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried the "change" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title and question are a little unclear. Do you want to catch the input event, the lost focus event, or both?

Look at catching `input` and `blur`.

```js
$('#inputEmail').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
})
$('#inputEmail').on('input', function () {
    console.log('input changes');
});

$('#inputEmail').on('blur', function () {
    console.log('left element');
});
```

```css
#inputEmail {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form action="#">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an input event for that

```
$('#inputEmail').on('input', function () {
    console.log('input');
});
```